# What is the accurate description of the use in "when use an array"

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers

> When we use an array, it is converted automatically to a pointer to its
>   first element. **(c++ primer 5th ed. pp129)**

```
int ia[3][4];

for (auto p = ia; p!= ia + 3; ++pp){
  for (auto q = *p; q ! = *p + 4; ++q)
     cout << *q << ' ';
  cout << endl;
}
```

The code snippet above is a good example for the quotation. `p`is a pointer **points to an array of four ints** and `q` is a pointer **points to int**

However, the for range based loop has different story

```
for (auto row: ia) // the code won't compile in fact 
  for (auto col: row)
```

Here, the type of `row` is the pointer **points to int** (reason the second loop won't compile). Why is that? Is this not the case of **use** the array?

Comment: Just use `std::array` or `std::vector` already.

Comment: imho pp.129 isnt the place where raw arrays should be discussed in a book called "c++ primer", maybe in appendix XVI :P

Comment: @MichaelNastenko -- a pointer points to an object that has a type. That type can be "array of four int". That's exactly what `p` is in the example code. `ia` is an array of 3 arrays of 4 ints; its name decays into a pointer to its first element, which is the first of the 3 arrays of 4 ints, i.e., an array of 4 ints.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko -- it is **exactly** true. The type of `ia[0]` is array of four `int`. In many situations that name **decays** into a pointer to its first element, but that's a consequence of **how it's used**; that does not affect its type. That decay happens in so many situations that programmers tend to forget that it's there, but if you ignore it you'll get bitten sooner or later. To see the difference, write a simple program that shows you `sizeof(ia[0]` and `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"use an array" is a very handwavy expression.

To understand how the array is used, you must first understand what the range based for loop does. Let's expand your outer loop to use an equivalent regular for loop (I've simplified a little):

```
{
    for (auto __begin = std::begin(ia), __end = std::end(ia);
            __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        auto row = *__begin;

        for (auto col: row); // oops. Cannot use range-for with a pointer
    }
}
```

The question here is, what will be the deduced type of `auto row`?

The result of `*__begin` is an l-value of type "array of 4 ints". `auto` follows the rules of template argument deduction. An argument cannot be an array object, so `auto` can never be deduced to be an array. The array type decays to pointer to first element i.e. pointer to `int` in this case.

An argument can be deduced as "reference to array of 4 ints", so this will work:

```
for (auto& row: ia)
    for (auto col: row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is `for (auto row: ia)` causes the element of `ia` to decay to a pointer so `row` becomes a pointer type.  This means you cant use `for (auto col: row)` since there is no begin function defined for pointers.

What you need to do is take a reference so that you refer to the 1d array and not have a pointer to it.  That looks like

```
for (auto& row: ia) // reference to each row in the array
    for (auto col: row) // copy of each element in the row
```

Comment: But why it is not "decay" to a pointer points to an array rather than the pointer points to the first element of the array (int here)

Comment: @SLN Because `std::begin`, which gets called on `ia` returns a 1d array because each element of a 2d array is a 1d array.  That 1d array(`int[4]`) decays into a `int*` which makes `row` a `int*`.